# Nvidia drivers cause Ubuntu 18.04 to hang on boot

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, dell

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Precision 5510.  This has both an integrated Intel HD Graphics 530 chip and a Nvidia Quadro M1000M card.  I am trying to get the better Nvidia graphics working with no luck.  I have used the latest 396 drivers I have tried many of the fixes described here and elsewhere with no success.  What always happens is the boot up hangs after I enter my hard drive password (encrypted) with an error that says "PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key"  I see this three times.

I have secure boot off which is required to use the DisplayLink drivers for external monitors.  Otherwise the external monitors don't work.

About the only thing I have not done is to use drivers downloaded from the Nvidia site as a few posts and videos have suggested that these are not stable.   I have considered falling back to version 384 of the driver which at least one person claimed to have been running with success.

Some posts have also claimed success by entering a key manually.  However I never get any prompt for that and I am not sure how to do that manually.

Any suggestions on how to get this running or at least debug this problem further.

I am technical, but new to Linux.

Comment: Nvidia recommends the "Linux Long Lived Driver" only for Quadros (which are very picky about Linux graphics drivers). That driver is 390.87.